# How to get JSON data into variable, parse, output as HTML

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, variables

I want to load JSON data into a Javascript variable, parse out some data and then display it in HTML.

The JSON data is obtained from the Yahoo finance API
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail

Im not even sure how to get the data into the variable. once I do I want to extract "name" and "price" and output them in an HTML table.

Comment: This is the topic of a tutorial or a chapter in a book, not an SO question.

Answer (score 1):

***With only JavaScript:***

If you request the WebService URL through [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest), you will get CORS issues:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

However, you can use the https://crossorigin.me/ service.

Then, you should request: «https://crossorigin.me/http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail». Finally, this can be easily used in JavaScript. You don't need to use jQuery.

I've made a demo.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var newXHR;

  // Helper function to make XMLHttpRequest without using jQuery or AngularJS $http service.
  function sendXHR(options) {
    //       (Modern browsers)    OR (Internet Explorer 5 or 6).
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (options.sendJSON === true) {
      options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    } else {
      options.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    newXHR.open(options.type, options.url, options.async || true);
    newXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", options.contentType);
    newXHR.send((options.type == "POST") ? options.data : null);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = options.callback; // Will executes a function when the HTTP request state changes.
    return newXHR;
  }

  // Call the WebService by using the helper function.
  sendXHR({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail",
    callback: function() {
      if (newXHR.readyState === 4 && newXHR.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(newXHR.response); // Store the WebServices JSON data to the «data» variable.

        var table = document.getElementById("table"); // Get the table.

        // Build the HTML table.
        var html = "<table><thead>";
        html += "<th>Name</th><th>Price</th>";
        html += "</thead>";
        html += "<tbody>";
        for (i = 0; i < data.list.resources.length; i++) {
          html += "<tr><td>" + data.list.resources[i].resource.fields.name + "</td><td>" + data.list.resources[i].resource.fields.price + "</td></tr>";
        }
        html += "</tbody></table>";
        table.innerHTML = html;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
#table table {
  border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table table td {
  border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

**Shorter version of this answer:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/9okhpebk/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON in javascript using `JSON.parse(strinfied_json)`.

JSON.parse converts the JSON to a plain-old javascript object, which you can query using the `[]` or `.` operators.

Here's an example:

```
var stock_data_json = "{
  list: {
    meta: {
      type: \"resource-list\",
      start: 0,
      count: 1
    },
    resources: [
      {
        resource: {
          classname: \"Quote\",
          fields: {
            change: \"19.061035\",
            chg_percent: \"0.404084\",
            day_high: \"4736.155273\",
            day_low: \"4684.284668\",
            issuer_name: \"NASDAQ Composite\",
            name: \"NASDAQ Composite\",
            price: \"4736.155273\",
            symbol: \"^IXIC\",
            ts: \"1462569359\",
            type: \"index\",
            utctime: \"2016-05-06T21:15:59+0000\",
            volume: \"0\",
            year_high: \"5231.940000\",
            year_low: \"4209.760000\"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}"

var stock_data = JSON.parse(stock_data_json)

// Get the first resource
var resource_0 = stock_data["list"]["resources"][0]["resource"];

var name = resource_0["name"];
var price = resource_0["price"];

$('#name_element').text(name);
$('#price_element').text(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery getJSON method:  jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )  to load JSON data into a Javascript variable from a url,
In the following example displayHtml is the function you want to handle the obtained data with:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail", displayHtml)
      .fail(function() {
        alert("no response from:  http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am unable to get your example working with the code below. the first alert fires, but nothing appears to work after the .getjson. I assume once working it will load the URL into displayHTML to be parsed?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
alert("startting");
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail", displayHtml)
  .fail(function() {
    alert("no response from:  http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail")
  });

alert("done");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```